# Error while building archive via terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, terminal, xcodebuild

I am trying to build ipa via terminal. I am getting below error. I am able to build ipa via xcode successfully.

Any help would be appreciate.

Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Not trying to split hairs, but when you say it builds in Xcode do you mean Archive - because you're passing in the archive option in terminal?